# How can I raise an event at a specific time in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, events

I made a web page for by AngularJS.

I want my web page to take action within a specific time.

for example,

If the 2016-01-07 11:00:00,

ng-show wants to take action.

Timer is using Angular-timer.

http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/?utm_source=angular-js.in&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=content-curation

However, I don't know how can I hold a event when the time changes to 0

Answer (score 2):

You can just make a real-time timer with plain Java and check with an if statement if it's the time you want. Like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.clock = "loading clock..."; // initialise the time variable
  $scope.tickInterval = 1000 //ms

  var tick = function() {
    $scope.clock = Date.now() // get the current time
    $timeout(tick, $scope.tickInterval); // reset the timer

    var d = new Date();
    if (d.getMonth() + 1 == 1 && d.getDate == 7 && d.getHours == 11) { //January is 0, February is 1, and so on
      //Your code goes here...
    }
  }

  // Start the timer
  $timeout(tick, $scope.tickInterval);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div>
    <p>{{ clock | date:'medium'}}</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

In this demo I used `.getSeconds`, but you can also do month, day, hours, minutes to get an alert on the date you wanted.

I hope this helped you enough :)

Comment: Thank you. It's very helpful for me.

Comment: You're welcome, btw I edited it a bit and now it works for the specific date you asked for :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to execute some code when the timer reaches 0, then just use the 'timer-stopped' event. Found [**here**](http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/examples.html#/angularjs-single-timer)

Just a tip: You can construct a valid date object by using a [**recognised format in the constructor**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) or by using [**Date.parse**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

This way you can check if your date/time target has occurred (or passed) by using:

```
var targetDate = new Date('2016-01-07 11:00:00');

function targetDateHasPassed() {
  return new Date() >= targetDate;
}

if(targetDateHasPassed()) {
  //...do stuff
}
```

Comment: I want to raise an event by checking the time, without the button. But, thanks to your insterest.